# Scikit Image Marching Cubes

Tags: python, mesh, scikit-image, marching-cubes

I'm using the Scikit Image implementation of the marching cubes algorithm to generate an isosurface.

```
verts, faces,normals,values = measure.marching_cubes(stack,0)
```

generates the following error:

> ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

but

```
 verts, faces = measure.marching_cubes(stack,0)
```

works fine so it seems the algorithm is simply not generating the values for `normals` and `values`. Has anyone had any experience with this type of issue?

Furthermore, I don't understand the need for the `faces` output of the algorithm, as a set of 3 vertices for each triangle in the mesh should be sufficient to describe the isosurface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#marching-cubes) of `marching_cubes` on the development version of scikit-image show that it should return `normals` and `values` as well. However it has only been introduced recently. They were not returned in version 0.12, as can be seen in the [docs from that version](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.measure.html#marching-cubes). To get them you'd have to update to the current development version. A guide on how to install the development version can be found [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html#running-the-development-version).

Answer (score 3):

from Version 0.14 marching_cubes() has-been removed

skimage.measure.marching_cubes has been removed in favor of skimage.measure.marching_cubes_lewiner

so make sure which version you are using.